# Dumping one class type with Django dumpdata

Tags: python, django, dump

I use dumpdata to output all my apps's classes. One of my app has one class that never get's outputted and I don't know where to start looking to know what's wrong. The class is used regularly, every other classes in the app are dumped fine and dumpdata doesn't throw any error.

Any clue ?

Comment: Does `manage.py dumpdata myapp.mymodel` work?

Comment: no but I am on 1.0.4,  I can't update yet and I think this came after 1.1...

I could have specified, but the model should be outputted any way as it's part of the app

Answer (score 1):

You might try serializing it to json and see if you get any errors there -- maybe there's a subtle inconsistency that's messing up the serialization.

```
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> from myapp.mymodels import mymodel
>>> serializers.serialize('json', mymodel.objects.all())
[...]
```

This might be worth a try too:

```
>>> serializers.serialize('python', mymodel.objects.all())
[...]
```